# Pull Up/Down vs High/Low Pull

Tags: microcontroller, resistors, switches, pullup, pulldown

Is pull up the same as high pull? Is pull down the same as low pull? If they are different what is the difference? These two terms are all mentioned in [this](http://wiringpi.com/the-gpio-utility/) guide and it is kinda confusing.

Comment: The only mention of "pull" in that document is in reference to "pull up" and "pull down". Where do you see "high pull" and "low pull"?

Comment: @NickJohnson In the `gpio write` command. It sets a output pin to high or low. Is this the same as setting a pin to pull up/down in the `gpio mode`command?

Comment: No mention of "high pull" or "low pull" that I can can find. Question should be closed.

Answer (score 5):

"High pull" and "low pull" aren't terminology I've seen used anywhere, including in the document you link to.

There is a difference between a pullup and driving high, or a pulldown and driving low. Enabling a pullup (or pulldown) connects the GPIO pin to VCC (or GND) via a resistor. If nothing else is driving the line, this makes it go high (or low), but still allows other devices to override it.

Driving the line high or low connects the GPIO directly to VCC or GND.